# Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated

Tags: javascript

I get the message: Use of `getUserData()` or `setUserData()` is deprecated. Use `WeakMap` or `element.dataset` instead.

I use the java script below. And don't understand what I have to change.

```
$(window).load(function status(){
  $(function status() {
        $.get('/status.php', function(data) {
            $('#valuedata').html(data['valuedata']); 
        });
        setTimeout(status, 10000);
  });
});
```

Comment: valuedata is an html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some of the problem with function creation you can use the below code instead of yours.This method contains setInterval which exactly executes after 1000 ms.

> Note: The `data['valuedata']` contains/return proper array like string
>   notation with output of `status.php` othervise you can use `$.makeArray()` to convert a string to array.

```
$(window).load(
function status(){  
        $.get('/status.php', function(data) {
            $('#valuedata').html(data['valuedata']); 
        });

}
setInterval(status, 10000);
});
```

Or you can go with your setTimeout

```
$(window).load(
function status(){  
        $.get('/status.php', function(data) {
            $('#valuedata').html(data['valuedata']); 
        });
    setTimeout(status, 10000);
}
setTimeout(status, 10000);
});
```

Comment: I believe there is a } too much on the top code. But after disable addblock plus and change to the top code it works. Both of you thanks

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion at the jquery forum about this one, apparently, **it came from the Adblock Plus addon.**

If you have the add-on installed, disable it and check.

*I do note that it was 4 years ago* **

Comment: Indeed I use addblock plus